# 401 - Forbidden: Access is denied. IIS

Tags: c#, .net, yahoo-oauth

[yahoo error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us56s.png)I'm receiving this error 401 forbidden - I'm not getting permission through yahoo's oauth. I've updated the key and secret which matches perfectly with my developer account. I'm not sure If I overlooked something with yahoo settings.

```
if (!isWeb) return;

// Only web uses external authentication.
var yhOptions = new YahooAuthenticationOptions
{
    ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YahooId"],
    ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YahooSecret"],

    Provider = new YahooAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            foreach (var claim in context.User)
            {
                var claimType = string.Format("urn:yahoo:{0}", claim.Key);
                var claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue,
                        "XmlSchemaString", "Yahoo"));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}

app.UseYahooAuthentication(yhOptions);
```

Comment: More info will be needed, please share some code

Comment: I figured the underlying issue, which was the incorrect URL callback domain path which didn't match what is specified on the project URL after checking it's properties.